# How can I copy the text that is located in a div in a form html

Tags: c#, html, httprequest, html-agility-pack

I've Tried this I'm getting an Error Do u maybe know why?
It gives me an error

````
            var Webget = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = Webget.Load(earlyLink);
            var ourNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(("//p[@class='product_note']"));

            foreach (var node in ourNodes)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(node.GetDirectInnerText());



            }```
This is the Error
````

Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebException: Connection refused Connection refused

Comment: This html page is part of your application? Or is it third party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a variant of the solution to your previous question.

The XPath to find the node you want is:

```
"//p[@class='product_note']"
```

And then to get the content use:

```
node.GetDirectInnerText()
```

If you're doing a lot of this, you really need to study the XPath and HtmlAgilityPack documentation.

Comment: It's really long I wrote the first two lines in the Post

Comment: That's a failure to connect to the website, nothing to do with reading the page.